# Uploading Image to Google Form Errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I've been really struggling with this. I am very very new to writing code, so bear with me.

I want to create a form with a file submission that parsers the responses into a google spreadsheet and places the file into a specific folder in *my gdrive, not the uploader's gdrive*.

I've have tried debugging and asking around, but no one can seem to figure out where my error is or how to place the uploaded files into my own folder, so I can have access to them/see them.

Here is the link to my code: https://script.google.com/d/appID/edit?usp=sharing

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: your link is not valid : Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.https://script.google.com/d/appID/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

here i can offer you a very simple script to copy the fileupload in your folder that you wish
and to write the value from the textfield to your sheet.

it is written simple but can give you the first steps.

copy code in your scripts file and run as google apps script.
before you run the scripts you have to change in the code the
uloadfolder ID and the ID from the sheet.
You find your own Id's when you browse to these elements in your googledrive
and read the ID's from the urlpath in your browser.

```
function doGet() {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var text_lbl        = app.createLabel('text: *');
  var text            = app.createTextBox().setName('text');  
  var replay_file_lbl = app.createLabel('Replay Upload:'); 
  var replay_file     = app.createFileUpload().setName('replay_file');
  var submit_btn      = app.createSubmitButton('Submit');

  var battle_result_tbl = app.createFlexTable();

  battle_result_tbl.setWidget(0, 0, text_lbl)
                   .setWidget(0, 1, text)
                   .setWidget(1, 0, replay_file_lbl)
                   .setWidget(1, 1, replay_file)                   
                   .setWidget(4, 1, submit_btn);

  var form_panel = app.createFormPanel()
                  .setWidget(battle_result_tbl);  

  app.add(form_panel);

  return app;
}


function doPost(e) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  // the uploads are writen in the root folder of google drive
  var upload_root   = DocsList.getFolder('');   

  // the dest folder for the uploads files       
  var upload_folder = DocsList.getFolderById('0B4Kg6cMbounaOHlMTXZUMUpTN3c');  

  var text          = e.parameter.text; 
  var replay_file   = e.parameter.replay_file;   
  var thx_lbl       = app.createLabel('Thanks for your submission!');

  app.add(thx_lbl);

 // workaround, use try & catch cause if no file uploaded then error "File name cannot be empty"
  try{
      var replay_file_id = DocsList.createFile(replay_file);  // create the uploaded file
      replay_file        = replay_file_id.getId();            // get the ID from uploaded file 
      replay_file_id.addToFolder(upload_folder);  // copy uploaded file from root to dest folder
      replay_file_id.removeFromFolder(upload_root);     // delete uploaded file from root folder
     } 
   catch(e){Logger.log('replay_file: '+e.message);}  

  // open ur sheet by id to write the value of text in
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-c4MkF2TLigtMGuWNk45Df51oZBlgI0xK5bkVUWxRH8');

  // this write the value from formelement text into cell A1
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).setValue(text);                                  

  return app;
}
```